# Run third party app as widget on my app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I wish to embed a third party application inside my own application. Think of it as if running the osx native calculator as a widget inside my own app.

I believe this should be possible with something like overriding the third party nswindow's view and/or making the app... windowless.

Has anyone done this or can suggest some nice approaches?

Comment: What do you mean by embedding an application inside your own? It's pretty trivial to put an app in your app's bundle and launch it when you need to. But it sounds like you want to do something else like put your own UI on a different app. There's no way to do that, nor would the makers of other apps want you to be able to do that in most cases, since you could then resell their apps as your own. Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want something like an iframe to incorporate another app inside mine. The purpose is to extend the app with some features it lacks, but using external windows/app would be a bit awkward so I want to somehow "merge" the UIs.